# Exclude certain apps from Google Play updates when not installed using Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, amazon-appstore

With the bickering going on between Google and Amazon, I've hit a large annoyance. The versions of Audible, Kindle, and Prime Video from the Play Store all have purchasing disabled. You have to use the website to buy things and then download them (or for Prime Video, stream them). That lets Amazon comply with Google's policy while continuing to not give Google any money (I'd say that's malicious compliance, and I applaud it, even if the user experience of it is worse off to a consumer like myself). If you get the apps directly from the Amazon Appstore for Android, the features disabled for Google Play version are present in the Amazon Appstore version.

I have both Google Play and the Amazon Appstore for Android installed on my Tab S7+. If Google Play updates the Kindle app, as an example, the purchasing ability will then be gone, and if I go into the Amazon Appstore app, it won't allow me to do anything to fix it there because they identify that the current version wasn't installed through their Appstore app. So Google Play can do anything it wants on the system, but other launchers are better about not touching software they don't manage. Likely because Google gives themselves a pass while holding external devs to a much more stringent set of controls.

In the case of the Kindle app specifically, it really screws things up. You have to uninstall and reinstall the app, and then you have to re-add/re-download/etc. all the books, which is somewhat flaky given there's no "download all" option, and I have a *ton* of books. A lot of the time, it will lock up a bit trying to bite off more than it can feasibly chew. Not really a big deal for Prime Video or Audible since I rarely download videos and my audiobook collection is somewhere small like a little over 375 audiobooks. Kindle has 2836 books, 102 documents (sideloaded books, like the free ones Tor.com releases monthly), and some 3511 comics (now that Comixology seems to have finished merging with the rest of Amazon.

Anyways, I hope that explains things clearly. Any advice would be appreciated. I'll note that my Galaxy Tab S7+ is not rooted, and I have no desire to do so. It's running Android 12.

I've disabled automatic updates across the board on the S7+ for now, but it's time consuming to do manual updates for patching while skipping over these 3 apps (thankfully, the list is alphabetized).

So, the crux question: Are there any ways to block Google Play from modifying an app installed from another source? I do still want to be capable to turn automatic updates back on again in the future.

It's extremely easy to misclick on the name of the app to skip when running updates in the Play Store, which would then require a full reinstall and redownload all of the files again to re-enable purchasing support again.

TL;DR: my Android apps installed from Amazon Appstore need to come from Amazon, period. If Google Play updates them, then in-app purchases are off the table, and the Amazon Appstore for Android will never give you an easy way to bring it back. At least their launcher behaves correctly by not updating things thaf were installed by Google Play. The biggest frustration part, by far, is that uninstalling and reinstalling wipes out the downloaded data (Prime Video for TV/movies, Kindle for ebooks, and Audible for audiobooks & podcasts).

I read a bunch of older threads before writing this, but most of the ones I came across were missing large chunks of data and they didn't really help much.

Comment: The main problem is that Amazon should use different packageNames for their apps distributed via Amazon AppStore. This is the only reliable way to solve this problem (or they change the app package names in the apps distributed via Play Store).